# Native DB queries in a Domain Model MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design

I have a built an MVC application with a model layer containing entities, data mappers and service classes. So far so good. But now I have a controller that need to show a report containing data from multiple db tables with no relation to any entities in my model. The report is built from a advanced MySQL query containing joins, SUM/AVG-selects. All I want is an array of the data so be shown in the VIEW.

1. Can I mix methods in my service layer, some that returns entities ("getById()") and some that just returns array of data from my database query ("getAdvancedReport()")?
2. Is it OK to put the db-queries right in the service layer? If not, where should they go? The data mapper feel wrong because its job is just to map my entites to the db, not to retrieve custom data.

Maybe just "Coding bureaucracy" but i need to do this right.

Cant find anything on the net other than simple CRUD examples of the domain model.

Comment: Is the Mysql Database the Domain or how are the models domain models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sub>Not really an answer .. more like pontifications with bottle of beer</sub>

You seem a bit confused about the point in having data mappers and even about domain object in general.

Data mappers are responsible for the information exchange between storage (which sometimes is an SQL database) and domain object. If you have even a bit normalized DB structure, the database entities and domain objects will not map 1:1. Mappers are made for specific domain object , not for the database tables. A single domain object can even have multiple mappers (for example: one mapper which stores data in DB, and one in session).

If your `Report` object has no domain logic, you can even use an active record. The pragmatic approach is to use them when the potential domain object has **only** CRUD with no domain logic. If there is some computation, stick with domain object + data mapper pair.

Service layer is for application logic, not storage logic. There should be no SQL in it. Service should mostly be governing the interaction between undetermined mix of domain objects and mappers. With the exception of mailing services and similar structures.

Also, usually on-line reports are dynamic. You can order the data, filter it and otherwise manipulate. You would end up with a service, which can manipulate the `Report` object, apply filter to it or extract data from said object. All this tinkering is "application logic".

> <sub>that's it ... I run out of beer</sub>

Comment: Well, that's not really an answer indeed I'd say

Comment: @Matthieu sometimes a more abstract answer is much more valuable than answering directly

Comment: Yes Im a bit confused about this, but your answer made me a little smarter

Answer (score 2):

> Can I mix methods in my service layer, some that returns entities ("getById()") and some that just returns array of data from my database query ("getAdvancedReport()")?

Yes, but I would correct your sentence as such: *some that returns entities and some that just returns **array of data***

=> the user of the service doesn't care where the entity/data comes from. So, yes your service can return entities *and* raw data (array of primitive types).

> Is it OK to put the db-queries right in the service layer?

No

> If not, where should they go?

In the Repository/DAO. It is OK to perform native queries in the Repository. And the Data Mappers are not used here, simply because we don't need to map entities.

**To sum up:**

Service->getMyData() > Repository->getMyData() > DB query

Comment: there is MVC tag at the bottom of this question ... you are talking about SOA.

Comment: @tereško He is talking about DDD and services in his question. I am not talking about SOA but about DDD.

Comment: Do not return array of data, return data you can iterate over.

Comment: @hakre you can't iterate over an array? Of course he can wrap up the data into whatever classes he fancies, but an array or data seems also fine to me.

Comment: That was just a suggestion to generalize the programming of the view. Sure you can foreach an array. But often if things come from some kind of store, you probably don't want to convert into an array in the first place.

Comment: I wonder .. how did you conclude, that this is domain driven design, if it is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @tereško the question's tags

Comment: @tereško I would agree that while there isn't much in this question about core DDD principles, repositories are a tactical DDD pattern and it can be difficult to understand the role of repositories for returning reporting information vs. entities and aggregates.

Comment: Actually I thought the use of entities/mappers/services is domain driven design :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK to put the db-queries right in the service layer? If not,
>   where should they go?

DB queries should be always placed **in data-mapper**, because "Service" shouldn't know, where are data from.